# Regular expression matching only URLs not having hyphen and four digits at the end

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to create IIS rewrite rule for product URLs. The regular expression for this rule should be matched only by URLs like this:

```
catalog/products/gl1800-airbag.aspx
```

or

`catalog/products/cab2.aspx`.

URL's like

`catalog/products/gl1800-airbag-2007.aspx`

or

`catalog/products/cab2-2007.aspx`

should not be matched. It doesn't matter how much hyphens the last part of URL can have, it only hould not end with something like "-0000" (year).
I am not good at regular expressions and managed to get only to this:

```
catalog/products/([^/-0-9]+)\.aspx$
```

Second URL will match it, but first not. I'm not sure how to set the number of digits here and even if my regex is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
catalog/products/(?![^/]*\d{4}\.)([^/]+)\.aspx$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rJ6uX7/1)

The `[^/]+` will match 1 or more characters other than a `/` and the `(?![^/]*\d{4}\.)` negative lookahead will fail  a match once it finds 4 digits right before a `.`.